# Convert QgsVectorLayer.extent() to EPGS:4326

Tags: extents, pyqgis-3, bbox

Many APIs such as overpass turbo require bounding box notation like `(x_max, y_max, y_min, x_min)` in EPSG:4326.
However the method `QgsVectorLayer.extent()` returns values in the source's CRS. A possible solution of course is to reproject the `QgsRectangle` as described [here](http://kartoza.com/en/blog/how-to-quickly-transform-a-bounding-box-from-one-crs-to-another-using-qgis/) long time ago. But I wonder:

Is there a way to easily return these coordinates in EPSG:4326 without having to reproject all the data i want to derive extents from?

I mean Qgis nativliy derives these coordinates when using the 'Identify Features' tool and also by glancing at the [sourcecode](https://github.com/3liz/QuickOSM/commit/a0a0c2debf5b7cec3a1da525702b507e786a4ae1) of the the plugin 'QickOSM' it seems capable of doing so.

Comment: What's wrong with the linked post? I would describe that as *relatively easy*. It's not projecting *all* your data, just the bounding box and I would say from the docs 
https://qgis.org/pyqgis/3.2/core/Coordinate/QgsCoordinateTransform.html#qgis.core.QgsCoordinateTransform.transformBoundingBox it accounts for the bounding box becoming a trapezoid when projected by taking the bounding box of the trapezoid - not 100% accurate but usually good enough.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with it. It was in fact applied eventually.